# Unable to add new GitLab remote in GitKraken if one or more remotes already exist

Tags: git, gitlab, gitkraken

I came accross a very strange behavior of GitKraken! I have three local repos and in order to have a backup on our company's "Self-Managed" GitLab server, I wanted to add a remote to each of them. With the first repo everything went well. I got the screenshot below, entered all the data, and was able to push/pull afterwards, as expected.

[image]

But then I tried the same with the second repo, and all I got was this:

[image]

I can enter the name, but the "Add remote" button does not become active and the dropdown list above is empty (even if I create an empty repo on the GitLab server manually).

Then finally after hours :-( I found out that as soon as one or more remotes already exist in the `.git/config` file, GitKraken does not show the first dialog anymore! Indeed the other two repos already had a `remote` entry in their configs.

Is this seriously an intended behavior? I mean its really strange! Why not allow the user to add a repo from scratch at any time? Or does anybody know a way how to force the first dialog to appear?